# sort one vector in a class and the second vector should move with the first

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to sort a `vector<vector<double> >` and record the original index with `vector<int>`

```
ex A[0][1].............[N], and A[0][0] = X, A[0][1] = Y, A[0][2] = Z
                    A[0] = (1,5,3), A[1] = (3,2,1) A[2] = (2,8,4) after sorting
    index:            0               1             2
                    A[0] = (1,5,3), A[1] = (2,8,4) A[2] = (3,2,1)
    original index :  0               2             1
```

so I write the following code, and I want to use the STL sort, but I don't know how to write the compare function.

```
class point{
    public:
    point(int totalLength = 0, int elementLength = 0);
    vector<vector<double> > pointSet;
    vector<double> pointIndex;
};
point::point(int totalLength, int elementLength){
    pointSet.resize(totalLength,vector<double>(elementLength, 0));
    pointIndex.resize(elementLength);
}
```

and suggestion or other way to achieve it?

Thank for your reading.

Comment: Why don't introduce special `struct Point` instead of inner `vector<double>`?

Comment: The input is a const vector<vector<double> >.

Comment: So, you have a chance to improve it replacing with `vector<Point>` (if it is actually vector of points). Think about it.

Comment: sorry, I cannot understand what you mean, can you say it more cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'm talking about is introducing separate data structure for points. Usually, when you talk about points and some geometry, you know exact number dimensions. 
So, you can use

```
struct Point
{
double x;
double y;
double z;
};
```

instead of

```
std::vector<double>
```

Even if you do not know number of dimensions, you'd better use

```
typedef std::vector<double> Point;
```

to represent a single point.

And your `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` becomes `std::vector<Point>`. It is just easier to read at least.

Then, it is impossible to sort 2 arrays simultaneously, using `std::sort`. So, you have to combine your `pointSet` and `pointIndex` array in one data structure  to sort.

An obvious way, you can create

```
typedef std::pair<Point, int> IndexedPoint;
std::vector<IndexedPoint> indexedPoints;
```

Then you fill this structure with given points and its indexes and then sort:

```
for(int indx = 0; indx < pointsSet.size(); ++indx) {
    indexedPoints.push_back(std::make_pair(pointsSet[indx], indx));
}
std::sort(indexedPoints.begin(), indexedPoints.end(), &lessThen);
```

Less then implementation depends on algorithm of comparison. For example, if you want to compare point by first coordinate, you can write

```
bool lessThen(const IndexedPoint& l, const IndexedPoint& r)
{
    return l.first.x < r.first.x; //or return l.first[0] < r.first[0]; -- ensure point has at lest 1 dimension here!
}
```